# Add a picture before book title

Tags: graphics, books

I want to add a logo picture on the title page. However, it appears that I could not make it before the title. Is it possible to do so, please? If so, how and how to make it centered and above the title?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\includegraphics[]{logo}
%opening
\title{abc}
\author{abc}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue here is, that you try to add a picture befor the `\begin{document}`. Your commands only set the content of `\title` but don't typeset it. You might use the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

%opening
\title{abc}
\author{abc}

\begin{document}
\vbox{
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}
    \maketitle %this typesets the contents of \title, \author and \date
}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Please note that I put the `\maketitle` and the `\includegraphics` in a `\vbox{}` to prevent it from pagebreaking in between the picture and the title.

EDIT: I've adapted the code to not use `\maketitle` in a `titlepage`-environment.

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to use `\maketitle` inside `titlepage`.

Comment: Note that something here is not centred. You can see that the date is not centred relative to the image, for example, although the title and author probably are.

Comment: @cfr looks very centered to me. Also the code doesn't have to be in a `titlepage`-environment. I didn't know that you don't put `\maketitle` in such an environment (heard it for the first time today). What's the reason to not do it?

Comment: @Skillmon I vote your answer, certainly.

Comment: @cfr encountered something funny: When you use really long author names the name isn't centered indeed (well it is centered but there is no linebreaking resulting in an overflowing hbox and therefor doesn't look centered). But this also happens if you just use `\maketitle` without my `\vbox` and `\includegraphics` and it happens with both the standard `book` class and `scrbook`.

Comment: The date is not centred in my test. `\maketitle` and `titlepage` both insert page breaks. You're suppressing that, but I'm not sure whether that is a good idea. (Well, you aren't now, but you were.)

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the explanations. The date is centred in my test. That's interesting. Did you change anything from the MWE?

Comment: No. I just compiled your MWE. The date is slightly to the left of centre. The author and title seemed to be centred, though.

Comment: @cfr for me it isn't. And I don't know what could produce this behavior on your machine. Did make any change to the `book`-class? You might set the picture to the width of `\today` and add a negativ `\vskip` to verify your findings.

Answer (score 9):

The `titlepage` environment is not meant for use with `\maketitle`. However, the `titling` package offers a half-way house which allows you to use `\maketitle` within the `titlepage` environment, along with any other commands you wish.

At least, so it says on the tin. In reality, you can't put other things *before* `\maketitle`.

However, the package also gives us a series of hooks and we can use one of those to include the image. For example,

```
  \renewcommand\maketitlehooka{%
    \begin{center}
      \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{cath-gadael-chartref}}
    \end{center}%
  }
```

So we could then say

```
\maketitle
```

to produce the title page.

[image: cat leaving home]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}

\title{abc}
\author{abc}
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{%
  \begin{center}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{cath-gadael-chartref}}
  \end{center}%
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

If you wished to add material after the date, or between the various elements of the standard title, you could define the appropriate hooks (`b`, `c` or `d`) or, for material afterwards, nest the `\maketitle` inside a `titlingpage` environment.

Comment: Very beautiful. I vote your question.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum, graphicx}
\author{LaTeXFan}
\title{\protect \includegraphics{example-image-a.png}\\[1cm] A very nice image}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
 \frontmatter
 \maketitle
 \mainmatter
 \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: While your code is nice, it doesn't solve the authors issue to put the picture BEFORE the title.

Comment: @Skillmon You have right. Excuseeeeeeeee meeeeeeee. I have understand now.

Comment: You don't have to excuse. Mistakes like this one happen. If you can adept your answer to cover this everything is fine.

Comment: Don't you get an error from your example? `Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }. ...cs{example-image}\\[1cm] A very nice image}`

Comment: @samcarter Yes of course but I had promised that when I have some free time I changed. At home at the moment I do not have access. If you prefer you can safely change my code.

Comment: Just add a `\protect` in front of the `\includegraphics` to get rid of the error.

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you so much. I corrected the mistake because of you. I return the favor.

Comment: While it would be working now you made a mistake during correction and have duplicated `\begin{document}` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

I would simply include the image in the `\title` as showed in other answer or a title page, but  another approach (closer to that you are trying) could be redefine `\maketitle` to accept  also a  `\logo` command in the preamble.

Below it showed an example making this with a very simple definition of `\maketitle` (no `\tanks`, etc.) See the content of `book.cls` if you want start with  the original definition. That code would be better placed in your own custom class (but then without `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`) in order to clean the preamble and reuse in another documents.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% redefinition of \maketitle with a logo ==============  
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\logo}[1]{\gdef\@logo{#1}}%
\def\maketitle{
\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\setlength\baselineskip{8ex}
\setlength\parskip{4em plus 1fil minus 3em}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,
height=.6\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{\@logo}\par
{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries \@title}\par
{\Large\scshape \@author}\par
\@date
\end{center}
\newpage}
\makeatother
%  end of redefinition  ===============================  

\logo{example-image}
\title{The Nice Title \\ of the MWE}
\author{The Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```